# Dynamically get key vault secrets in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

**Is there a way to determine which secret and setting names are returned from Key Vault and App Configuration tasks dynamically so that I can use them in scripts and other tasks?**

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline

**Background**

I have a Key Vault and App Configuration service in Azure and I want to read a subset of secrets and settings from them in several Azure Pipelines (yaml and regular releases). I don't know how may secrets or settings there are nor their names except for a prefix as this is dynamically provisioned trough (amongst other things) bicep. I can use the Key Vault and App Configuration tasks to read values from the respective services, but there does not seem to be any way dynamically determine which values it reads and what their names are.

This seems like one of the most basic operations one should expect to be provided (give me a list of variables set), but no documentation describes this and all examples seems to assume I know exactly what the names of each secret and setting are before they are used. E.g.: using `$(mySecretName)`. This makes it impossible to create dynamic environments and it requires me to hard code names in many different locations or find hacky workarounds that parse config files and generate yaml pipelines. And for regular releases it just doesn't work at all.

Edit: To clarify, I know that loading configurations can easily be done in code. That is not the issue. What I need is to get a full list of which settings and secrets are defined from App Configuration and Key Vault tasks so that I can map them to (among other things) appsettings.json directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to determine which secret and setting names are returned from Key Vault and App Configuration tasks dynamically so that I can use them in scripts and other tasks?

Not an expert for App Configuration, but for keyvalut, if the secrets are dynamically created and you don't know their names, you can list all secrets to get the name, and set them as secrets in pipeline, filter them if needed. Steps below, hope it helps.

Step1:
create an ARM service connection on DevOps, add the service principal enough role(I simply add `contributor`, `Key Vault Administrator` role ) on keyvault.

Step2:
Add Azure CLI task on Pipeline:

[image]

script as below:

```
# Set the variable
$vaultName="wadekeyvalut2" # The name of the key vault

# Get all the secrets in the vault
$secretNames = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $vaultName --query "[].name" -o tsv

# Loop through each secret and get its value, you can remove the output as it's secret, the output is just for testing.

foreach ($secretName in $secretNames) {
    $secretValue = az keyvault secret show --name $secretName --vault-name $vaultName --query "value" -o tsv
    Write-Output "Secret name: $secretName, Secret value: $secretValue"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$secretName;issecret=true]$secretValue"
}
```

I output the secrets name and value for checking, you can remove the output as they are secrets.
[image]

With above script, we get the secrets name and set them as secrets variable in devops.

Edit:

Since you are using `Azure App configuration` task, and task will:

[image]

It's not supported to list the variables, you have to know the variable name before you invoke them.

Comment: Yes, but then I need another connection to the key vault for that CLI and not all values are necessarily relevant (I only need those directly referenced from the App Configuration instance). We have the task to extract App Configuration settings using a key prefix and it also resolves key vault values. All I want is the list of keys and values that it returns in some form that I can use in PowerShell or in other parts of the pipeline.

Comment: I know I can easily build a custom script to redo all the steps that the App Configuration and Key Vault tasks do, that is not the issue. The problem is that these tasks allow getting an unknown number of settings or secrets since they allow filters (e.g.: prefix with "myservice*"), but they do not provide any way at all to figure out which values the actually retrieve. This means I have to know at compile time all the names of all the settings and secrets in multiple different locations (pipelines + code + bicep) which is a pain to maintain.

Comment: Not understand why the script already got the keys but not retrieve the values(it should get the value). But since the secrets/keys are stored in external azure service(app configuration, keyvalut), it should be not achieved to get the names and values during `compile` time.  The only possible way is using two pipelines, 1st to get the names and values, and transfer to the 2nd pipeline as parameters. for example, transfer with variable in `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` task.

Comment: I'm probably not explaining it very well. I am quite able to get the keys and values using the taks. The problem is that there is no way to list them and map them without already knowing their names. This restriction prevents me from creating a generic pipeline that doesn't have to be updated every time a single secret og setting is added. All I need is the list of key/values from the AppConfiguration task so that I can dynamically populate some settings files. But that list is apparently not accessible.

Comment: Are you getting the key/values with rest api or script? It should be able to get the names and values as i shown above(keyvalut). If you are using existing tasks, it should not able to get as the values are secrets type, which won't be mapped into devops environment. Once you get the names and value, you can use logging command to set it as variable, and use them in next steps.

Comment: "Are you getting the key/values with rest api or script?" Neither, as I wrote initially, I'm using the App Configuration task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline) as I was hoping to avoid having to rewrite the resolution mechanism. I know that I can easily write a custom script for this, but I was hoping there was a way to just list each variable and value in a pipeline in a generic manner as that would allow MUCH more flexibility when building pipelines and I wouldn't have to write a utility that, frankly, should already exist.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your clarification, if you using the existing task `Azure App Configuration`, then it's NOT supported to list the variables as they are set as secret variables which not mapped to agent environment. I have edited the reply with details.

Comment: That is what I figured out, but I believe the reasoning for blocking that type of interaction is flawed and makes it impossible to create adaptable and dynamic pipelines. I guess the actual solution is to create something custom.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you, @Thomas, currently the only way I have on my roadmap to solve the problem is doing all the processing from a Java / python script which retrieves vault secrets by directly connecting to vault, collects and processes all the vault secrets, thus enabling me to output them as I want for another task or just use them for my purpose. Did you find any other way?

Comment: Hi @TudorVintilescu, good to know I'm not the only one. I ended up using basically your workaround except in Azure PowerShell as the cmdlets for [Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-11.1.0) and [App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.appconfiguration/?view=azps-11.1.0) closely match the parameters and behaviour of their equivalent ADO tasks. I haven't yet needed to share settings between jobs/stages, so for now I'm ignoring that problem of moving secrets between agents in a secure way.

Answer (score -1):

We have a list of configurations that we setup with a key, environment, keyvault and certificate.  This means you can then pass in a guid or other string to cross reference then look it up and apply that configuration.  The azure user will also need to have the correct login access to access that specific configuration, keyvault and certificate.  This can be from az login or using visual studio.

Your settings object should match the keys in your configuration on azure.

so then from your configuration object you can do something like the following:

```
string url = $"https://{configuration.KeyVault}.vault.azure.net";

var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(url), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        var properties = await client.DownloadCertificateAsync(configuration.Certificate, null, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());

        if (properties.Value.Thumbprint != null)
        {
            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                // Load the configuration using labels
                options.Connect(AZURE_APPCONFIGURATION)
                    .Select("*", "YourGlobalSettings") // Applies to all environments regardless
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });

                options.Connect(AZURE_APPCONFIGURATION)
                    .Select("*", environmentSpecificLabel) // Development, Production etc
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });
            });

            builder.Build().Bind(settings);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Thumbprint doesnt match.");
        }

        return settings;
```

This will probably take a bit of playing about, but you hopefully get the idea.  Also you can always make this driven from the environment of the project etc instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that solution does not work for us. We have existing applications that rely on appsettings.json which is currently populated from pipeline vars. We want to gradually move to App Config + Key Vault and one step is to populate the file from App Config in the pipeline itself. The problem is that our appsettings.json expectes keys with . separators which is not how we store them in app config and key vault (we use - so that the names can match exactly). We cannot change the c# code of our app, only the pipeline itself.