# What is the best way to load values from an Azure DevOps variable group into a file?

Tags: docker, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am currently working on some ADO pipeline templates to help a team build a handful of similar pipelines. The current YAML template looks like this:

```
# templates/run-script.yml
parameters:
  - name: dockerImageName
  - name: targetScript
  - name: variableGroupName


jobs:
- job: 'Run_Script'
  variables:
    group: ${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}
  steps:
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      artifact: ${{ parameters.dockerImageName }}_image
      path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo 'Loading docker image tarball'
        docker load < ${{ parameters.dockerImageName }}_image.tgz
        echo 'Running script in container'
        docker run -e foo=$(foo) -e bar=$(bar) -e baz=$(baz) ${{ parameters.dockerImageName }} ${{ parameters.targetScript }}
```

The variables `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are variables from the variable group being passed into the template with the `variableGroupName` parameter. In this case `baz` would contain a secret. The issue I'm having is that those variable names will differ when I reuse the template with different variable groups, and so this template isn't actually useful for keeping my code DRY in it's current state. What I would like to do is create a file `env.list` that would contain:

```
foo=(value of foo)
bar=(value of bar)
baz=(value of baz)
```

Which would allow me to rewrite the last line of the template as:

```
    docker run --env-file env.list ${{ parameters.dockerImageName }} ${{ parameters.targetScript }}
```

I need some way to get the name-value out of the variable group and into that file. So far I've tried a Bash task to get the variables with `az devops variable-group variable list`, but I couldn't figure out a way to parse them properly. What would be the best way to achieve this? Alternatively, if this is a bad approach, what would be the best practice solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve the goal you are looking for is to use an API to retrieve they keys and values of all the variables stored within your variable group.

API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

Powershell script to save all secret values into a file named `env.list`:

```
$variableGroupId = "117"
$sourceOrganization = "org"
$sourceProject = "project"
$sourcePat = "pat"
$sourceBase64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$sourcePat"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$sourceOrganization/$sourceProject/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$($variableGroupId)?api-version=7.1-preview.2"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic $sourceBase64Pat") } -Method get -ContentType "application/json"

$jsonString = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $result.variables
$resultObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $jsonString

foreach ($property in $resultObject.PSObject.Properties) {
    $key = $property.Name
    $value = $property.Value.Value
    Add-Content -Path "env.list" -Value "$($key)=$($value)"
}
```

Screenshot of variable group:

[image]

Output file `env.list`:

```
bar=barValue
baz=bazValue
foo=fooValue
secret=
```

However, as you mentioned that you have secrets stored in your variable group, these are not obtainable via API, see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/secret-variables-is-null-when-read-through-rest-ap/224229

My suggestion to get around that is to use some kind of secrets vault such as Azure Key Vault, then you can create a script to do something similar to my above script. Here is another answer that may help with that: [Dynamically get key vault secrets in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443867/dynamically-get-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

Comment: This is a a helpful start. The way we currently have it configured, our variable groups are linked to a key vault to pull the sensitive variables. I could migrate all the variables into the key vault and just use the method described in the last link, which would be fine, but couldn't I just use the Azure CLI to pull from the variable group instead?

Comment: To my knowledge, Azure CLI cannot pull anything from Azure DevOps, you would need to use the the Azure DevOps API like my answer is doing, which has the limitation of not allowing secrets.

I would recommend using the Azure DevOps task AzureCLI@2 or AzurePowerShell@5 to easily authenticate into Azure with a service connection, and then make sure you setup the service connection with the correct privileges to get keys from the vault using CLI or the Az powershell module.